# Finding the complex structure which induces an almost complex structure (example)

Tags: differential-geometry

Given an almost complex structure (i.e. an endomorphism $\widetilde{A} : TM \rightarrow TM$ such that $\widetilde{A}^{2}=-$Id) defined by: $\widetilde{A}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}}\right) = e^{x_{2}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}}$ and $ \widetilde{A}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{2}}\right) = -e^{-x_{2}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{1}}$, what is the corresponding complex structure $A : M \rightarrow M$ (if it exists) which is induced by $\widetilde{A}$?

Many thanks to all answers and comments, please ask if I need to give more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a couple of clarifications. You seem to be assuming that $M$ is a $2$-dimensional smooth manifold, and that it has a global coordinate chart with coordinate functions $(x_1,x_2)$; I'll assume this in what follows.

Next, I think you misunderstand the definition of a complex structure. Given a $2$-manifold $M$, a ***complex structure*** on $M$ is a covering of $M$ by coordinate charts $(U_\alpha,\phi_\alpha)$ taking their values in $\mathbb C$, such that where any two of them overlap, the transition map $\phi_\alpha\circ\phi_\beta^{-1}$ is holomorphic. A complex structure is induced by the given almost complex structure $\widetilde A$ if each coordinate map $z$ satisfies $Vz=0$ whenever $V$ is a $(-i)$-eigenvector of $\widetilde A$.

Note that a complex structure is *not* a map from $M$ to itself.

With these understandings, you can approach the problem as follows. A little linear algebra shows that the $(-i)$-eigenspace of $\widetilde A$ is spanned at each point $(x_1,x_2)$ by the vector
$$
V = i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} - e^{x_2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}.
$$
We're looking for a (locally defined) function $z$ satisfying $Vz=0$.

The form of $V$ suggests trying for a coordinate function that's a real-valued function of $x_1$ alone plus an imaginary-valued function of ${x_2}$ alone: $z = u(x_1) + iv(x_2)$.
Then $Vz=0$ reduces to $i u'(x_1) - i e^{x_2}v'(x_2)=0$, which is equivalent to 
$u'(x_1) = e^{x_2}v'(x_2)$.  Since the left=hand side is a function of $x_1$ alone and the right-hand side is a function of $x_2$ alone, this equation can hold only if both sides are constants. Multiplying $z$ by a constant doesn't change the complex structure, so we might as well take the constant to be $1$. This leads to the solutions $u(x_1)=x_1$ and $v(x_2) = -e^{-x_2}$, or
$$
z = x_1 -ie^{-x_2}.
$$
By another stroke of luck, this coordinate function is globally defined and is a diffeomorphism onto its image.

So the desired complex structure is given by the single coordinate chart $(M,z)$, where $z(x_1,x_2)  = x_1 -ie^{-x_2}$.

Comment: Okay I see, that makes sense. Great answer, thanks for your help!

Comment: Additional, I think I realise some confusion I had, because a complex structure on a real vector space $V$ is defined as an endomorphism $: V \rightarrow V$ which squares to minus identity. I (wrongly) took the same definition for a complex structure on $V = M$, a manifold.

Comment: Can I ask a further question. Generalising this to the case of $2n$-manifolds, the $(-i)$ eigenspace of an almost complex structure is spanned by $n$ vectors $V_{1}, \ldots , V_{n}$. Here, what would the coordinate map $\phi : M \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n}$ need to satisfy? For instance, for $n=1$ above you constructed $z$ to satisfy $Vz = 0$.

Comment: Given vector fields $V_1,\dots,V_n$ spanning the $(-i)$-eigenspace locally, you need to find a coordinate map $\phi=(z^1,\dots,z^n)\colon M\to  \mathbb C^n$ satisfying $V_i z^j=0$ for each $i$ and $j$. But in that case there's a necessary condition called _integrability_ that the complex structure must satisfy. Check out any book on complex manifolds.